# Row merging based on two conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently cleaning my data set for a farm and I need to merge the records from 3 separate rows into one.
I'd like the get all the records merged based on columns FARM and SHED.

The dataset currently looks like this:
[image: Current state of dataset]

Ideally, I wish to make it look like this:

[image: Desired results]

What is the best solution to have it cleaned up?
I'd like to move columns 'Feed total' and 'Feed per bird' to fill the empty spaces in the rows above. Then I'd like to move around the columns 'Average weight 1A' to row, where the shed number is 1, 'Average weight 2A' to row, where the shed number is 2 etc...

Thanks!

EDIT: Sample dataset attached to give a bigger picture on the dataset

| Date | Time | Age | Mortality day | Mortality total | Feed total | Feed per bird | Water total | Water per bird | Farm | Shed | DT | Average weight 1A | Average weight 1B | Average weight 2A | Average weight 2B | Average weight 3A | Average weight 3B | Average weight 4A | Average weight 4B | Average weight 5A | Average weight 6A | Average weight 5B | Average weight 6B | Average Weight 6A[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2MD2.png) | Average weight 7A | Average weight 8A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:01 | -1.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 182.0 | 0.004 | Park Farm | 1 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:01 | -1.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 105.0 | 0.003 | Park Farm | 2 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:01 | -2.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 4.0 | 0.0 | Park Farm | 4 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:01 | -1.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 82.0 | 0.003 | Park Farm | 3 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:01 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Park Farm | 1 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 | 2494 | 0.0 | 2577.0 | 0.0 | 2460.0 | 0.0 | 2467.0 | 1972.0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:00 | 4.0 | 94.0 | 367.0 | 600.0 | 0.018 | 1473.0 | 0.044 | Green Farm | 1 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:00 | 4.0 | 72.0 | 239.0 | 340.0 | 0.01 | 1480.0 | 0.044 | Green Farm | 2 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:00 | 4.0 | 94.0 | 288.0 | 630.0 | 0.019 | 1443.0 | 0.043 | Green Farm | 3 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:00 | 3.0 | 88.0 | 176.0 | 290.0 | 0.009 | 487.0 | 0.015 | Green Farm | 4 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:00 | 3.0 | 105.0 | 248.0 | 520.0 | 0.016 | 365.0 | 0.011 | Green Farm | 5 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:00 | 3.0 | 72.0 | 168.0 | 560.0 | 0.017 | 289.0 | 0.009 | Green Farm | 6 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Green Farm | 1 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 | 1861 |  | 1874.0 |  | 1990.0 |  | 2083.0 |  | 1959.0 | 2160.0 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:01 | 27.0 | 40.0 | 1153.0 |  |  | 11649 | 0.249 | Castle Farm | 1 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:01 | 26.0 | 21.0 | 941.0 |  |  | 11289 | 0.261 | Castle Farm | 4 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:01 | 26.0 | 22.0 | 962.0 |  |  | 10277 | 0.236 | Castle Farm | 3 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:01 | 27.0 | 53.0 | 1004.0 |  |  | 12204 | 0.259 | Castle Farm | 2 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:01 |  |  |  | 6686.8 | 0.139 |  |  | Castle Farm | 1 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:01 |  |  |  | 6446.9 | 0.146 |  |  | Castle Farm | 4 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:01 |  |  |  | 6031.5 | 0.135 |  |  | Castle Farm | 3 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:01 |  |  |  | 6742.5 | 0.14 |  |  | Castle Farm | 2 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:01 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Castle Farm | 1 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 | 1.508 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:01 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Castle Farm | 4 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1.542 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:01 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Castle Farm | 3 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  | 1.493 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:01 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Castle Farm | 2 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  | 1.542 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:01 | 24.0 | 36.0 | 1211.0 | 6380.0 | 0.156 | 9769.0 | 0.24 | Blue Farm | 1 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:01 | 24.0 | 31.0 | 1317.0 | 5860.0 | 0.144 | 9775.0 | 0.24 | Blue Farm | 2 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:01 | 24.0 | 29.0 | 1431.0 | 6470.0 | 0.159 | 9571.0 | 0.236 | Blue Farm | 2 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:01 | 24.0 | 28.0 | 947.0 | 5710.0 | 0.139 | 9755.0 | 0.238 | Blue Farm | 4 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:01 | 24.0 | 29.0 | 1089.0 | 6020.0 | 0.136 | 10399 | 0.234 | Blue Farm | 5 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:01 | 24.0 | 30.0 | 1489.0 | 5640.0 | 0.128 | 10303 | 0.234 | Blue Farm | 6 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:01 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Blue Farm | 15 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1289.0 | 1267.0 | 1268.0 | 1243.0 |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:01 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Blue Farm | 5 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 | 1418 | 1257.0 | 1462.0 | 1320.0 | 1332.0 | 1309.0 | 877.0 | 1248.0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:38 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |  |  | 0.0 | 0.0 | Upper Farm | 38 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:38 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |  |  | 0.0 | 0.0 | Upper Farm | 3 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:38 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Upper Farm | 1 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2.849 |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:35 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 34.0 | 0.001 | Seaside Farm | 1 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:35 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 35.0 | 0.001 | Seaside Farm | 2 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:35 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 26.0 | 0.001 | Seaside Farm | 3 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:35 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 35.0 | 0.001 | Seaside Farm | 4 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 23:50:35 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Seaside Farm | 5 | 2022-06-06 23:50:00 | 39 | 40.0 | 43.0 | 42.0 | 45.0 | 46.0 | 46.0 | 46.0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include some sample data in text or table form rather than linked images?

Comment: @Toothless204 dataset added as per request

Answer (score 2):

I would start like this, this is assuming you only want one row/record per farm-shed.

```py
import pandas as pd
import functools

# dataframe is df

# First combine horizontally: get the average weight into one column

weight_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith("Average weight")]
df2 = (
 df.assign(**{
    'Average weight': lambda df: functools.reduce(pd.Series.combine_first, [df[col] for col in weight_cols])
 })
 .drop(columns=weight_cols)
)


# Get first value from each column in each group

grouped_by = ['Farm', 'Shed']
remaining_cols = df2.columns.difference(grouped_by, sort=False)

(df2.groupby(grouped_by)
    .agg({col: "first" for col in remaining_cols})
    .reset_index())
```

*If* you want to safeguard against duplicated data, more checks are needed.